# Free text editor with image gallery

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi i want a free text editor with image or file gallery and i want to insert image or file in the middle of the text.
Please give me your suggestions.

Comment: Hi please take a look on [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to provide much information for us. You haven't told us what platform, what framework, what kind of editor (wysiwyg or plain-text)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ckeditor(text)+ckfinder(image)
Or
you can use [Summernote](http://summernote.org/)  with server side image upload setup

```
$('#Editor').summernote({
        lang: 'fa-IR',
        callbacks: {
            onImageUpload: function (files) {
                var $editor = $(this);
                var data = new FormData();
                data.append('imageFile', files[0]);
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Server/UploadImage',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: data,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function (url) {
                        $editor.summernote('insertImage', url);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

and MVC5 server side sample action code:

```
 public string UploadImage()
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase file = null;
        string RenameFile = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
        {
            file = Request.Files[i];
            string fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            Guid randomFileName = Guid.NewGuid();
            RenameFile = randomFileName + fileExt;
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads/"), RenameFile);
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }
        return @"/Content/Uploads/" + RenameFile;
    }
```